# Check if some object in ArrayList fulfills some condition

Tags: java, lambda, mapping, arraylist, conditional-statements

I have an `ArrayList<Person> persons`.  I want to check if some person in persons fulfills a condition. Like: `person.isFemale()`

Instead of looping the list, is there any nicer way to perform this? Some mapping or lambda way maybe?

Edit:

Hello and thanks for the replies!

I think I asked the wrong question.. 
I want to check if any object in the list differ from any other: 
boolean different = (if isMale() && isFemale()) somewhere in the list.

Comment: Please do not add noise like "Regards Filip" to questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Guava, but you would "looping the list" with `Iterables.any` anyway.
If your condition of your `Person` never change while being in the list, than use a custom subclass of ArrayList (or other list impl) and check the condition in the insertion methods.

Comment: If the head of the list matches the condition, `Iterables.any` will return after 1 comparison.  For normally distributed data this is O(n/2) instead of O(n)

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend Guava (formally Google Collections), specifically [Iterables.any](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#any%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) to test if a single instance matches a condition or [Iterables.all](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#all%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) to test if all instances match a condition.  You can set your predicate to either match some logical expression or test all elements are equal to the head of the list.

This isn't doing anything fancy under the hood, but it does at least get you into the habit of writing code in the functional style.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/index.html):

```
List<Person> persons = ...;     

List<Person> matchingUsers = Collections2.filter(persons, new Predicate<Person>() {

    @Override
    public boolean apply(Person person) {
        return person.isFemale();
    }
});

if (!matchingUsers.isEmpty()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer `Iterables.any` over `Collections2.filter` so you don't have to evaluate the entire list after finding the first match.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you "loop the list" to find out something about a Person instance - if you have a reference to the Person, simply use that. I can only assume that you meant the question to say:

> How do I find Person instances that match a certain condition?

If so, you could sort the list using a Comparator that sorts Persons with isFemale() low, so they go to the head of the List, then you could loop until person.isFemale() was false, like this:

```
List<Person> persons = ...; 
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Person>() {
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        return o1.isFemale().compareTo(o2.isFemale()); // Note: Assumes isFemale returns Boolean, not boolean. Otherwise, wrap before comparing.
    }
});

for (Person person : persons) {
    if (!person.isFemale()) {
        break;
    }
    // Do something with females
}
```

Note: This isn't a *good* idea, because it's going to be slower than just traversing the list in the usual way, however I was trying to answer the question as stated.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the replies!

I think I asked the wrong question..

I want to check if any object in the list differ from any other:

boolean different = (if isMale() && isFemale()) somewhere in the list.

Regards
Filip

Comment: This is even worse, the list is potentially traversed twice.

Comment: I agree! I didn't say this would perform well, but I was grappling with the OP question trying to give him some kind of solution that met the question.